# In React, is it good practice to have a container handle both authentication and fetching data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a React app with a container that handles both authentication and fetching data. If a valid oauth access token is false, the container redirects to a login page. If a valid oauth access token is true, then the container continues to fetch data to pass to a child element. Now, is it good practice to have the container handle both things?

```
--------------------     ---------------------- 
|                  |     |                    |   
| Container        |-----| Child              | 
|                  |     |                    | 
--------------------     ----------------------   
Check auth.               Gets data from 
Redirect if necessary.    Container via props.
Make endpoint call.       Render data.                        
Pass data obj to                  
Child A.
```

An alternative would be to have another container to handle the authentication. If authenticated, then render nested container which handles the fetching of data:

```
--------------------     ----------------------     -------------------
|                  |     |                    |     |                 |
| Container A      |-----| Container B        |-----| Child A         |
|                  |     |                    |     |                 |
--------------------     ----------------------     -------------------

Check auth.               Make endpoint call.        Gets data from
Redirect if necessary.    Pass data obj to           Container via props.        
                          Child A via props.         Render data.
```

Which would be better practice?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best practice to handle authentication is not at the component level but with the use of routers. Take a look at this example:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';

import {readFromStorage} from './../utils/storage/index';

import Login from './../components/Login';
import Main from './../components/Main';
// If user doesn't have tokens, send them to Login page
function verifyAuth() {
    const user = readFromStorage('token');
    if (!user) {
        browserHistory.push('/');
    }
}
// If user logged in before and has tokens skip login page
function checkTokens() {
    const user = readFromStorage('token');
    if (user) {
        browserHistory.push('/main');
    }
}

export default (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/">
        <IndexRoute component={Login} onEnter={checkTokens}/>
        <Route path="main" component={Main} onEnter={verifyAuth}/>
    </Route>
    </Router>
);
```